# Resize uploaded image in MVC 6

Tags: image, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the best way to resize an uploaded image in MVC 6? I'd like to store multiple variants of an image (such as small, large, etc.) to be able to choose which to display later.

Here's my code for the action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPhoto()
    {
        if (Request.Form.Files.Count != 1)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];

        // calculate hash
        var sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create();
        byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(file.OpenReadStream());

        // calculate name and patch where to store the file
        string extention = ExtentionFromContentType(file.ContentType);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(extention))
            return HttpBadRequest("File type not supported");

        string name = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(hash) + extention;
        string path = "uploads/photo/" + name;

        // save the file
        await file.SaveAsAsync(this.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path));
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using Image Processor library.

http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/

Then you can just do something along the lines of:

```
using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory())
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path))
{
    file.Value.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    imageFactory.FixGamma = false;
    imageFactory.Load(file.Value)
                .Resize(new ResizeLayer(new Size(264, 176)))
                .Format(new JpegFormat
                {
                    Quality = 100
                })
                .Quality(100)
                .Save(fileStream);
}
```

Where `file.Value` is your file that was uploaded (the stream) (I don't know what it is in MVC, this is code I use in a Nancy project)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need!

Comment: @Phill Great link, thanks, the only thing I've found for vNext image. But does the "new Size" is the System.Drawing part?

Comment: @voo the current Nuget still requires System.Drawing, but the API is changing for V2 to drop that constraint. https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor#api-changes

Comment: the problem with imageproccessor library is that it requires ,net full framework, but if you want to use .net core , so far i have not found any solution.

Comment: @elhampour The new API is working on .NetCore, still very much a work in progress though.