# Asp.NET core Image resizing

Tags: image-processing, asp.net-core

How can I resize the uploaded image in asp.net mvc 6? System.Drawing is no longer available Are there any third-party plug-ins with similar features and support vnext. I tried ImageProcessor  and some others - it did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize uploaded image in MVC 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901860/resize-uploaded-image-in-mvc-6)

Comment: Is the front end or back end of the resize you want

Comment: I tried ImageProcessor. It is not supporting vnext yet.
I need it on backend.

Comment: https://github.com/imazen/Graphics-vNext

Comment: ImageProcessor Core is still in alpha (beta soon) but certainly works to resize images now.

Comment: I always used `WebImage` for this process.  You could [attempt to import it](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1351).

Comment: just released my image resize tool for .NetCore: http://ziyad.info/en/articles/29-Image_Resize_for_NetCore

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my purpose by manipulating it on client side with javascript in canvas. As asp.net core is cross platform yet there isn't any Drawing and Graphics related api provided by Microsoft for .net core. But in your case it is web and you can always handle it on client side.